# What is the expected amplitude of the flat frequency response of a Kronecker delta function? Does sample rate affect it?

Tags: frequency-response, impulse-response, dirac-delta-impulse

I was instructed [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/91871/38609):

> *In the sampled-time domain* a Kronecker delta, $\delta(n)$, has a perfectly flat spectrum.  If you look at a table of discrete-time Fourier transform pairs, this is at the top of the list: $\mathcal F^{-1}\left \{ \delta(n) \right \} = A$, where $A$ is a positive real number whose value depends on how the author likes to treat their Fourier transform pairs.

I am not educated on these matters, so I am not sure reading this.

What is the expected amplitude of the frequency response of a Kronecker delta relative to the amplitude of the single sample spike? Is it sample rate dependent?

Or is this suggesting amplitude of each frequency will be $A$ if the Kronecker's amplitude is $A$ also regardless?

For example, if you are sampling at 44100 Hz, and have a single sample at amplitude $A$ with all others zero, what amplitude do all sampled frequencies excite to? Do they all excite to $A$?

If you then sample at 88200 Hz, and do the same, does the same result occur, or is the amplitude of the frequency response sample rate dependent in any way?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Once you're in discrete time, there is no sample rate.  Or better yet, in discrete time, the sample rate is equal to 1 and is dimensionless.  It is 1 sample per sample period.

Comment: And there's a lotta horseshit with all this $A$ crap.  $$ \mathscr{F} \big\{ \delta[n] \big\} = 1 $$ Fuck that $A$ crap.

Comment: The Kronecker Delta IS the "single sample spike". Are you confusing this with the Dirac Delta?

Comment: I mean the kronecker. I am simply asking if the kronecker has an amplitude of 0.5 does that mean all frequencies are excited equally to 0.5 amplitude?

Comment: @mike: yes, of course. That follows directly from the definition of the DFT